# Why aren't the Bootstrap 3.0.1.1 glyphicons displaying in IE8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

I download the latest version of `Bootstrap`, `version 3.0.1.1` using Nuget and I am using it in a `Visual Studio 2012 ASP.NET MVC 4` application.

After the download it only put the following files in the Content directory:

- bootstrap-theme.css
- bootstrap-theme.min.css
- bootstrap.css
- bootstrap.min.css

And in my Scripts directory the following:

- bootstrap.js
- bootstrap.min.js

I've also included the `Respond.js` and `html5shiv.js` files.

When I run the application in `IE8` it doesn't seem to find the glyphicons that I put on my views.  There are just squares that seem like placeholders where the glyphicons should be.  When I run the application in the latest version of `Firefox` then it is there.  I don't understand why?

Can anyone please share some light?

Answer (score 2):

i think hanselman wrote a post about this last week...
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhyDoMyFontAwesomeIconsShowUpAsBlankSquares.aspx

> Then you realize that you need to have class="fa" as well as whatever the icon's class is.